# Typescript map not awaiting result

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, async-await, nestjs

I'm using a many to many relation with TypeOrm who is needing Ids to find the subcategories of an article.

The problem is that the map is not awaiting to push the result in the array.

Here is my map function with the list and the logs:

```
const subcategories = articleDto.subcategoriesIds.split(',').map(x => +x)
const subcategoriesList = []
    
await subcategories.map(async (subcategoryId) => {
    console.log('start:' + subcategoryId)
    const category = await this.subcategoriesService.getSubcategoryById(subcategoryId);
    console.log('mid:' + subcategoryId)
    await subcategoriesList.push(category);
    console.log('end:' + subcategoryId)
});

console.log('### ' + subcategories);
console.log('### ' + subcategoriesList);
```

Here is the output of the logs:

```js
start:2
start:3
### 2,3
### 
mid:2
end:2
mid:3
end:3
```

I'm not understanding why the result is not awaited, thanks for the help if you know how to manage with this problem.

EDIT: Solved this issue by adding a `Promise.all` using map inside

```js
const subcategories = articleDto.subcategoriesIds.split(',').map(x => +x);

const subcategoriesList = await Promise.all(subcategories.map((subcategoryId) => {
      return new Promise((resolve => {
        this.subcategoriesService.getSubcategoryById(subcategoryId).then(result => {
          resolve(result);
        });
      }))
    }));
```

Comment: Please don't use `.map` for simple iteration. Use `.forEach` or an actual loop instead.

Comment: `.forEach` is not asynchronous, I will use promises instead of map.

Comment: The point is not to misuse `.map`. It's not just a tool for iterating over a dataset. It's for performing *mapping*.

Comment: Yes I understand, so the solution is to use a `.for` loop because `.forEach` is not asynchronous ?

Comment: You can use a regular loop if you want to process these sequentially or fire off all requests, then await them all at once with `Promise.all`. Depends on whether you want to process these sequentially or in parallel. Since there doesn't seem like there is dependencies between your requests, `Promise.all` seems like the better choice. That's what the linked duplicate shows.

Comment: Yes I will use the `Promise.all` with the array of promises, thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Array prototype methods don't await even if they are async. The code fires in a synchronous manner still. If you need these to await you can do

```js
const subcategories = articleDto.subcategoriesIds.split(',').map(x => +x)
const subcategoriesList = []

for (const subCategoryId of subcategories) {
  console.log('start:' + subcategoryId)
  const category = await this.subcategoriesService.getSubcategoryById(subcategoryId);
  console.log('mid:' + subcategoryId)
  await subcategoriesList.push(category);
  console.log('end:' + subcategoryId);
}

console.log('### ' + subcategories);
console.log('### ' + subcategoriesList);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I try to develop without using for function... Is it not possible to use promise instead of await to await all promises after iterations ?

Comment: Why develop without using a for functions? There's litereally answers all over saying this is how to do exactly what you're looking for? I suppose if you _really_ want to avoid `for` loops you could `map` it and then `await Promise.all(returnedArrayFromSubcategories.map)`

Comment: I don't use the for loop following the [airbnb javascript style guide](https://airbnb.io/javascript/#iterators-and-generators)

Comment: Interesting. While array functions are generally easier to read, and more succinct, there are absolutely times to use `for of` instead of `map` or `every`. This being one of them. Another being when performance is what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes you'r right, I just always used to follow this style guide used in many companies maybe sometimes by mistake. I will check the `for` loop in more details tomorrow !